# Typed data over a MessageBox?

Tags: serialization, ipc, deserialization, dart, game-engine

I'm thinking about writing a Dart based browser game. I like to separate the core game logic from the client render and event handling code. This way i can run the same logic code on the server Dart VM side in a multiplayer system. This is what lots of games doing today (eg. Quake series): you have a local server even if you play a single player game.

So in my scenario:

- Event handling and rendering runs on the main browser thread (render loop is triggered by [requestAnimationFrame](http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/))
- Game logic runs in a separate [Isolate](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/contents/ch03.html#ch03-dartisolate---concurrency-with-isolates) (actually a [WebWorker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_worker) in the browser)
- For communication i'm using [MessageBoxes](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_isolate/MessageBox.html) which is a bit cumbersome to setup and manage but it's possible. This can be later exchanged with a WebSocket if the logic runs on the server.

The logic isolate sends messages to the main thread loop about game events (like a game object's status is being updated, map change, etc.) and the main thread posts client side events (key press based player movement, commands) to the logic.

I'm wondering about what's the best way to manage messages over this layer. From the documentation of MessageBox: *"The content of message can be: primitive values (null, num, bool, double, String), instances of IsolateSinks, and lists and maps whose elements are any of these."* These are all good for simple data transmission but what if i like to pass whole data beans? The only solution i found is JSON serialization which can be done relatively painlessly with [JsonObject](http://www.dartlang.org/articles/json-web-service/#introducing-jsonobject). Now we have a String which can be passed over the MessageBox/WebSocket.

I wonder how good this design is? JSON serialization and deserialization occurs for each data on the connection. I'm affraid of the overhead this introduces, this channel will be used a lot.

Is there anything i can do to improve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple possibilities:

1. Does sending a typed data list work? The VM should be able to transfer typed data lists between isolates. Not sure how dart2js handles things.
2. Take your binary data and base64 encode it into a String for transmission. This will be slightly less compact than pure binary data (1.2x space increase) but will work.

John